# MySQL Query to return zero against attribute if not present on particular day

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a MySQ query for following results
I have used following query to get the below

```
select date(modified_date) as date,category_rating,count(*) from  fms_process_feedback group by date,category_rating;

Date        subcategory  count
2015-05-20  good         1
2015-05-21  bad          1
2015-05-25  bad          1
2015-05-25  good         1
2015-05-26  bad          6
2015-05-26  good         16
```

I need query to return data in below format

```
Date        subcategory  count
2015-05-20  good    1
2015-05-20  bad     0
2015-05-21  bad     1
2015-05-21  good    0
2015-05-25  bad     1
2015-05-25  good    1
2015-05-26  bad     6
2015-05-26  good    16
```

I need query to return zero instead if there is no entry for particular date for subcategory good or bad like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all subcategories and dates.  So, first generate the rows using a `cross join`.  Then bring in the data using a `left join`:

```
select d.dte, r.category_rating, count(f.modified_date)
from (select distinct date(modifed_date) as dte from fms_process_feedback) d cross join
     (select distinct category_rating from fms_process_feedback) r left join
     fms_process_feedback pf
     on date(pf.modified_date) = d.dte and
        pf.category_rating = r.category_rating
group by d.dte, r.category_rating;
```

Comment: Hey Gordon,How can i get good count and bad count in a columns for a particular date ?